# Why cannot I change the root context to "/" in my JBoss AS?

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x

I have a maven project for my java enterprise application that is deployed on a JBoss 7.1 server.

In my EAR module I have this pom.xml

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>myproject</finalName>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>myproject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproject-webservice</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                            <unpack>false</unpack>
                        </webModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>myproject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproject-ejb</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I would like to set the root context to `/` so I can go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. But JBoss won´t deploy if the root context is `/` saying:

```
08:00:54,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 36) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service
```

But if the root context is something else than `/`, like `<contextRoot>/myproject</contextRoot>`, it works (but then I have to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myproject` ).

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: first delete existing root.ear from jboss then try

Comment: I tried, but the same problem occured. Look at my comment to Juned Ahsan´s post below. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/198890

It stands:
AS7 comes with a default application deployed to `/` context. When you hit localhost:8080, you'll be shown a page which has a message which says:

`To replace this page set "enable-welcome-root" to false in your server configuration and deploy your own war with / as its context path.`

I just changed the standalone.xml and that was the solution! :-D